# Python 3 - Why wont my simple program do anything with the input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, calculator

i just started learning Python 3. So i learned some basics and tried writing something on my own. Its a little calc, but after the user does its inputs nothing happens, it justs ends. Sorry if this is a very stupid Question. Thanks in advance

```
print("Welcome")
n1 = float(input("Please insert a number"))
o1 = input("Please insert the operator(+,-,*,/)")
n2 = float(input("Please insert another number"))

def mult(x, y):
    z = x * y
    return z


def addi(x, y):
    z = x + y
    return z


def subi(x, y):
    z = x - y
    return z


def divi(x, y):
    if x == 0 or y == 0:
        print("Cant divide 0")
    elif x == 0 and y == 0:
        print("Cant divide 0")
    else:
        z = x / y
        return z


if o1 == "+":
    addi(n1, n2)
elif o1 == "-":
    subi(n1, n2)
elif o1 == "*":
    mult(n1, n2)
elif o1 == "/":
    divi(n1, n2)
else:
    print("Wrong Operator!")
```

EDIT: Thanks to all of you, I fixed it and it works. Thanks again.

Comment: You need to `print` it.

Comment: OH MY GOD! I was definitely to close to the problem. I feel dumb now haha Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing the calculations, but not outputting them :

```
if o1 == "+":
    print(addi(n1, n2))
elif o1 == "-":
   print(subi(n1, n2))
elif o1 == "*":
   print(mult(n1, n2))
elif o1 == "/":
   print(divi(n1, n2))
else:
    print("Wrong Operator!")
```

**NOTE:**
There is a mistake in your `divi` function, use this instead :

```
def divi(x, y):
    if y == 0:
        print("Cant divide by 0")
    else:
        z = x / y
        return z
```

**+** You can just return the result without storing it in a variable :

```
def mult(x, y):
    return x * y
def addi(x, y):
    return x + y
def subi(x, y):
    return x - y
def divi(x, y):
    if y == 0:
        print("Cant divide by 0")
    else:
        return x / y
```

Comment: friend small typo print(addi(n1, n2)

Comment: Why only check for y ? What about if x = 0 ?

Comment: you will get >>> 0/4 0.0

Comment: In maths, or math :p, for every number a, 0/a = 0 (exists), but a/0 is undefined, so we only check for the second number y.

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly may be you just want to print the result 
Add print

```
print("Welcome")
n1 = float(input("Please insert a number"))
o1 = input("Please insert the operator(+,-,*,/)")
n2 = float(input("Please insert another number"))

def mult(x, y):
    z = x * y
    return z


def addi(x, y):
    z = x + y
    return z


def subi(x, y):
    z = x - y
    return z


def divi(x, y):
    if x == 0 or y == 0:
        print("Cant divide 0")
    elif x == 0 and y == 0:
        print("Cant divide 0")
    else:
        z = x / y
        return z


if o1 == "+":
    print(addi(n1, n2))
elif o1 == "-":
    print(subi(n1, n2))
elif o1 == "*":
    print(mult(n1, n2))
elif o1 == "/":
    print(divi(n1, n2))
else:
    print("Wrong Operator!")
```

Output

Welcome

```
Please insert a number34
Please insert the operator(+,-,*,/)+
Please insert another number23
57.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You calculates operation results, but use it anyway - so it not changes program state (e.g. not writing in standart output).

See next:

```
if o1 == "+":
    addi(n1, n2)  # addi return value not used
elif o1 == "-":
    subi(n1, n2)  # subi return value not used
elif o1 == "*":
    mult(n1, n2)  # mult return value not used
elif o1 == "/":
    divi(n1, n2)  # divi return value not used
else:
    print("Wrong Operator!")
```

As you can see - return values not used.

Let's see functions

```
def mult(x, y):
    z = x * y
    return z


def addi(x, y):
    z = x + y
    return z


def subi(x, y):
    z = x - y
    return z


def divi(x, y):
    if x == 0 or y == 0:
        print("Cant divide 0")
    elif x == 0 and y == 0:
        print("Cant divide 0")
    else:
        z = x / y
        return z
```

It's just return values, but not output it anyway.

So you need to print return values. E.g. -

```
if o1 == "+":
    print(addi(n1, n2))
elif o1 == "-":
    print(subi(n1, n2))
elif o1 == "*":
    print(mult(n1, n2))
elif o1 == "/":
    print(divi(n1, n2))
else:
    print("Wrong Operator!")
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @LuigiDavinci welcome I would suggest since you are using python 3.0 do use floor division  http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/floor_division.html

Comment: @HariomSingh but that wouldn't give me the correct result though, would it? it would print 2.0 when asked what 5/2, so I though since its a float why not divide accurately or am I missing something